# Получение разрешения экрана

Tags: экран, javascript

В сети нашел пример получения разрешения экрана.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>  document.write('Разрешение экрана: <b>'+screen.width+'×'+screen.height+'px.</b>'); </script>
```

Возвращает - *Разрешение экрана: 1138×640px.* , хотя реальное разрешение 1366×768.

Как получить правильное разрешение?

Comment: какой браузер/OS ?

Comment: firefox/windows

Comment: проверьте что zoom нет, и ещё я видел баг с windows vista какой-то на эту тему.

Answer (score 20):

Есть несколько вариантов определение экрана, это касается как десктопных браузеров, так и мобильных.

Варианты:

1. Размеры экрана девайса\монитора
2. Размеры окна браузера
3. Размеры без инструментов браузера (навигационной панели например)

**Первый вариант:**

`window.screen.width` и `window.screen.height` отвечают за размеры экрана.

**Второй вариант:**

`window.innerWidth` и `window.innerHeight` отвечают за размер окна браузера.

**Третий вариант:**

`window.screen.availWidth` и  `window.screen.availHeight` отвечают за непосредственный размер области отвечающей за вывод информации (очень полезно в мобильных браузерах)

Answer (score 5):

Вы получили размер окна. Получить разрешение экрана можно так:

```
var h = window.screen.availHeight;
var w = window.screen.availWidth;
```

Comment: вот как-то так:

    console.log(window.screen.height,window.screen.availHeight)
    1080 1056

Answer (score 2):

для видимой области экрана

```
 var scrollHeight = Math.max(
        document.body.scrollHeight,
        document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
        document.body.offsetHeight,
        document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
        document.body.clientHeight,
        document.documentElement.clientHeight
    );
```

подробно [тут](http://itforweb.com/content/e410/)