# Как сделать, чтобы скрипт выполнялся при определнных разрешениях экрана?

Tags: javascript

Добрый день мне необходимо чтобы этот скрипт выполнялся при заходе с мобильного

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "scrollY":        "200px",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "paging":         false
    } );
} );
```

А при заходе с десктопного выполнялся вот этот скрипт.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]]
    } );
} );
```

Как это сделать? Спасибо

Comment: определить мобильный и выполнить первый, может ваш вопрос должен звучать так? - "Как определить разрешение экрана"

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Получение разрешения экрана](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/243682/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Comment: @Jean-Claude Мой вопрос звучит правильно. Суть в том, что первый скрипт выводит таблицу полноразмерную с табуляцией не адаптированную под мобильные устройства, а второй скрипт делает из этой же таблицы адаптированную без табуляции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
if(screen.width <= 600) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "scrollY":        "200px",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "paging":         false
    });
  });
}
else {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]]
    });
  });
}
```