# Реальное разрешение экранов устройств пользователей. Анализ Я.Метрики и Г.Аналитики

Tags: адаптивная-верстка, яндекс-метрика, аналитика, разрешение

Дорабатываю сайт под мобильные устройства. Хочу понять, какие в основном разрешения экранов пользуются спросом среди пользователей моего сайта.

Создал отчеты по разрешению экранов и типов устройств в яндекс.метрике и гугл.аналитике.

Вижу что довольно много пользователей с шириной экрана от 320 до 400. Кто эти люди? Разве так много на руках смартфонов с таким малым разрешением экранов.

Далее начинаю внимательнее смотреть в статистику и вижу, например

```
Galaxy A5 - 360x640
Redmi Note 7 - 393x851
Redmi Note 4 - 360x640
и т.д.
```

Но ведь это не соответствует действительности. Метрика и аналитика неверно определяют разрешение экранов?

Неужели есть смартфоны в таком большом количестве с шириной экрана от 320px?
Необходимо ли оптимизировать дизайн и под такое малое разрешение экрана?

Кстати, в инструментах разработчика браузера хром, можно посмотреть как сайт будет отображаться на мобильных устройствах. Там также "недостоверные" размеры экранов смартфонов отображаются, например для Galaxy S5 360x640.

Почему так? чего то я не понимаю...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

1) Нашел ответ - devicePixelRatio. Оказывается в мобильных устройствах используется параметр devicePixelRatio, когда одному пикселю сайта соответствует несколько пикселей мобильного устройства. Подробности тут: https://habr.com/ru/post/159419/

2) Далее для своего huawei P30. Разрешение экрана 1080x2340 точек.
Вычислил разрешение "мобильного экрана" с помощью javascript (Подробности тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/243802/305545):

```
<script>
alert(window.screen.height);
alert(window.screen.width);
</script>
```

Получил: 424x918. Теперь все стало ясно.