# Проверка размеров экрана в javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Каким образом в javascript можно проверить размеры экрана (в if-е) и в зависимости от этой проверки отрисовывать содержимое страницы? Меня интересуют устройства типа IPad (tablet.js) (используются ли в них скролл)?

Answer (score 0):

Это можно это сделать методом [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)

```js
function check(){
  if( window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)").matches ){
    console.log('подходит');
  } else {
    console.log('не подходит');
  }
}

check();

window.addEventListener( 'resize', check );
```

Только нужно учитывать, что в медиазапросах может учитываться или не учитываться скроллбар в разных браузерах. Поэтому вместо этого могут лучше подходить более конкретные методы определения. Например `document.documentElement.clientWidth`.

Comment: а какой из методов, указанных на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/243682/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0/243802 можно использовать для адаптивной верстки?

Comment: @htmllayout можно много разных методов использовать, все они имеют свои осбенности - учитывают или нет скролл, отталкиваются от размера body/документа/окна/монитора и так далее. Например смотрите эту картинку с какого-то сайта - https://web-designer.cman.jp/javascript_ref/window/size/size.gif

Comment: Данный ответ был к прошлой версии вопроса. @htmllayout данный ресурс не рассчитан на постепенное изменение вопроса и подгонку ответов под эти изменения. При изменении вопроса ответ обесценивается и может не соответствовать. Лучше продолжать в комментариях или в чате или какой-то форум найти, где живое общение.

Comment: У айпадов сколл не учитывается, потому что он появляется "поверх" страницы. Оба метода из ответа подходят.